# Request.AnonymousID in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using MVC 4 Web API and the Anonymous Identification Module to identify anonymous users for a shopping cart in my application. This is the value I've added to my web.config file:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

I can access `Request.AnonymousID` in a normal `Controller` but not an `ApiController`. How can I access this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the following using statement

```
using System.Web;
```

then use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID
```